# Word or phrase (M-W sense) for power fantasy

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What's a word or longer phrase that can be used to talk about living out a fantasy of power? Getting high on power?

"Power trip" comes to my mind but I think there's another one

> Do you think people crave the ______ ?

Comment: dictator fantasy/

Comment: @EdwinAshworth what does M-W sense mean?

Comment: The multi-word sense (ie a string of two or more orthographic words, perhaps not including open compounds). Contrast a conflicting definition: 'Noun phrases do not have to contain strings of words. In fact, they can contain just one word' [[UCL ... Internet Grammar](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/phrases/define.htm)] Note that this assumes that a 'string' contains over 1 word, again a debated usage. // If we allow 'phrase' to cover single words here, 'SWR's are subsumed by 'Phrase requests'. But arguably a change needs to be made to tags.